# Can I avoid repeat calculation in this query?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

To match points close to a point at latitude and longitude `(point_lat, point_lon)` I need to do something like this,

```
SELECT id, lat, lon,
ACOS(COS(RADIANS(ABS(lat - point_lat))) * COS(RADIANS(IF(ABS(lon - point_lon) > 180, 360 - ABS(lon - point_lon), ABS(lon - point_lon))))) as angle_between
FROM places;
```

the `IF(ABS(lon - point_lon) > 180, 360 - ABS(lon - point_lon), ABS(lon - point_lon))` part of the query really hurts my eye, looks like `ABS(lon - point_lon)` is calculated 2 times, unless MySQL optimizes `IF` internally.

The `places` table is quite large (~6 million rows) so I am looking to do this as efficiently as possible. Do you have any suggestions?

**EDIT:** **`ABS(lon - point_lon)` is not that expensive to calculate, I know that**. But as a matter of fact, the `angle_between` I select in the query, needs to be like **`angle_between = IF(angle_between > 180, 360 - angle_between, angle_between)`** and **calculation of `angle_between` is quite expensive.**

I know I can use derived tables, the query becomes :

```
SELECT t.id, t.lat, t.lon, t.angle_between, if(t.angle_between > 180, 360 - angle_between, angle_between) as angle FROM (
    SELECT id, lat, lon,
    ACOS(COS(RADIANS(ABS(lat - point_lat))) * COS(RADIANS(IF(ABS(lon - point_lon) > 180, 360 - ABS(lon - point_lon), ABS(lon - point_lon))))) as angle_between
    FROM places
) AS t
ORDER BY angle LIMIT 20;
```

A 'custom MySQL function' also seems like an option, but I am not so sure about their performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not worry about the time spent doing the calculation for `ABS(lon - point_lon)`.  This should be a minor part of the calculation, especially when using trigonometric functions.  In fact, for most queries, the time spent *accessing* the data dominates the query; not the time spent running functions.  This is not always the case, but in your query the `ACOS()` and other functions will take more time.

If you don't want the explicit `if()`, you can also use:

```
greatest(ABS(lon - point_lon), 360 - ABS(lon - point_lon))
```

EDIT:

In your *particular* case, you could do:

```
IF( (@x := ABS(lon - point_lon)) > 180, 360 - @x, @x)
```

This is only guaranteed to work because all the logic is in one statement (which is why I didn't propose it first).  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluations of expressions in a `select` clause, so you shouldn't use `@x` in any other expressions.

Other options, such as using a subquery or `union all` require reading and writing more data.  That is a high threshold for performance gains (you can always test the alternatives to see if they work better, just don't be too optimistic).  In other words, there are no really good solutions, although the variable method might work best for your particular case.

Comment: `ABS(lon - point_lon)` is just an example... there are cases where the value is a huge expression containing 5-6 trig functions... I know I can use derived tables, but am not sure about performance...

Comment: @Optimus . . . In MySQL, a derived table is going to incur the overhead of materializing the table.  That would probably be more expensive than doing the calculation.

Comment: What about custom mysql functions?